# How can I map a stock's specific sector over a period of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, quantitative-finance

I am having trouble mapping stock specific sectors over a period of time. To give you an example.
Here is the sector data of a stock.

```
ticker     sector_code   entry_date   exit_date
abc        sec1          20080501     20110504
abc        sec2          20110505     20120403
abc        sec3          20120404     NA
```

Time period is 01-01-2008 to 01-01-2020.
I would like to create a table like this:

```
             abc
2008-01-01   no_sector
...
2008-05-01   sec1
2008-05-02   sec1
...
2011-11-11   sec2
...
```

My basic instinct is to use loops and if statements. But I found out that it would be so complicated and computationally expensive. I could not figure out any other ways to do this. Would you please give me a hand? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert values to datetimes and replace missing values by another column
df['entry_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entry_date'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['exit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['exit_date'], format='%Y%m%d').fillna(df['entry_date'])

print (df)
  ticker sector_code entry_date  exit_date
0    abc        sec1 2008-05-01 2011-05-04
1    abc        sec2 2011-05-05 2012-04-03
2    abc        sec3 2012-04-04 2012-04-04

#for each row create date range and concat together
s = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.entry_date, r.exit_date)) 
                          for r in df.itertuples()])

#create new DataFrame and join original data with filtered columns by list
df = (pd.DataFrame(s.index, index=s, columns=['date'])
        .join(df[['ticker','sector_code']])
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
           date ticker sector_code
0    2008-05-01    abc        sec1
1    2008-05-02    abc        sec1
2    2008-05-03    abc        sec1
3    2008-05-04    abc        sec1
4    2008-05-05    abc        sec1
        ...    ...         ...
1430 2012-03-31    abc        sec2
1431 2012-04-01    abc        sec2
1432 2012-04-02    abc        sec2
1433 2012-04-03    abc        sec2
1434 2012-04-04    abc        sec3

[1435 rows x 3 columns]
```